# Can I customize toolbar default action in Closure JS?

Tags: javascript, closures, google-closure-library

I want to customise toolbar action in **closure js**.
I want to give class-name to `font-color` palette.

I came up with creating a custom toolbar button from scratch.
But it takes so long.

So, If I can give class-name to `font-color` palette then I use it.
If I can't it then I give up it.

Palette A

```
<div class="goog-menu goog-menu-vertical"> <!-- This element -->
    <div class="goog-palette">...</div>
    <div class="goog-palette">...</div>
</div>
```

Palette B

```
<div class="goog-menu goog-menu-vertical"> <!-- This element -->
    <div class="goog-palette">...</div>
    <div class="goog-palette">...</div>
</div>
```

There are under `<body>` when the `font-color` button pushed after background-color button.

I want to uniquely identify these.

Comment: This is a help site , You are here for asking help so no need to request for help or beg for help. :)

Comment: Thank you for edit request.